# Get name of current UBER rider with UBER API?

Tags: uber-api

If all I want to pull is the current riders either first name last initial or first initial and last name is that possible without having to have a customer login to either my app or to give access to my app through UBER? I am trying to construct a simple lighting app where the riders name can be displayed on a screen or led light for better recognition of who a driver is picking up. Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: This is not possible without authentication. See the [Uber API documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/references/api/v1/partners-me-get) on driver profiles.